# I wanted to know why it showing error like this or is that goint to make any problem for me after deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

```
warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#how-it-works
Error: Aborted because ./pages/login.js is not accepted
Update propagation: ./pages/login.js -> ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?absolutePagePath=D%3A%5CJimmy%5Cwork%5Cclient%5Cpages%5Clogin.js&page=%2Flogin!
    at applyHandler (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1670508348862:881:31)
    at http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1670508348862:564:21
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

I wantes to know more about this error and how i can solve this error

Comment: Why do you think it says `Error` and `Aborted`?? Aldo how did you attempt to learn more on the error? Did you search for solutions?

Comment: Yes i have researched answer but i dont get any proper answer on this error